# Django jquery file upload: linking to another model

Tags: python, django

Setting up django-jquery-fileupload https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload and it works, here's the model

```
# encoding: utf-8
from django.db import models


class Picture(models.Model):
    """This is a small demo using just two fields. The slug field is really not
    necessary, but makes the code simpler. ImageField depends on PIL or
    pillow (where Pillow is easily installable in a virtualenv. If you have
    problems installing pillow, use a more generic FileField instead.

    """
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.file.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('upload-new', )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.file.name
        super(Picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """delete -- Remove to leave file."""
        self.file.delete(False)
        super(Picture, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

and the view

```
# encoding: utf-8
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import CreateView, DeleteView, ListView
from .models import Picture
from .response import JSONResponse, response_mimetype
from .serialize import serialize


class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Picture
    fields = "__all__"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        files = [serialize(self.object)]
        data = {'files': files}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        data = json.dumps(form.errors)
        return HttpResponse(content=data, status=400, content_type='application/json')
```

for now ignoring how behind the scenes it uploads the images, what I do however need to figure out is there is another model `UserService` which needs to be linked to `Picture` either using `ForeignKey` or `ManytoManyField` so the pictures are items on the userservice.

If you have an idea on how to implement this so it works on upload.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would go for the `ForeignKey` relationship and in the model `UserService` add the following variable `picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture, blank= True, default=None)`. You can change the options for `blank` and `default` and am assuming that the model `UserService` will be linked to the `User` model, so the first line in the model `UserService` should be ` # This line is required. Links UserService to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)`.

Comment: thanks to a slack group suggested I just pass the info to form_valid and save it from there, ended up using a cookie.